# How do I use Bintray with Grails when applying plugins to my app?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

Today's the first time I encountered Grails 3 and I'm quite overwhelmed of all the changes to the framework coming from 2.4. One such change is the application of plugins. I'm not very familiar about how Bintray works but I understand that's where plugins are hosted now. So if I want to apply a plugin into my app, how do I do that?

In particular, I've been meaning to add [Grails GORM REST client](https://grails.org/plugin/gorm-rest-client) plugin to the project. I'm not sure if Grails 2 plugins are compatible with Grails 3 application, but I searched in Bintray and found a [similar entry for GORM REST client](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-rest-client/view). There are no documentation for it yet, so I'm not sure what I'm looking at that page exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The `form-rest-client` plugin is not yet available for Grails 3.0, you can see the available plugins at https://bintray.com/grails/plugins

Comment: I see. 1.0.0 isn't working on 2.x, though; there's a problem with `pluginManager` property being invalid or something. Anyway, in 3.x, is applying a plugin as simple as adding a gradle dependency?